# Scala slick left join doesnt work

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Im a newbie to Slick.

I would like to get the list of ids from Echo table that DO NOT exist in programs_vw table.

I have written the SQL query which works

```
SELECT f.`id`
FROM `Full`.`programs_vw` f
LEFT JOIN `FULL`.`Echo` e ON f.`id`=e.`id`
WHERE e.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY f.`id`;
```

I have referred to the examples in http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html and wrote this but it doesnt work

```
 val query = for {
      (t, f) <- echoQuery.filter(_.id.isEmpty) join programsVwQuery on(_.id === _.id)
      } yield (f.id)
db.run(query.to[List].result)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more why it doesn't work? What's the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all what you did is not a LEFT JOIN (I am talking about Slick version). In order to generate it you need to use `joinLeft` method.

However this straightforward correction is wrong - it produces *subquery* which is bad.

```
for {
      (_, p) <- echoQuery.filter(_.id.isEmpty)
               .joinLeft(programsVwQuery).on(_.id === _.id)
} yield (p.map(_.id))
```

Side note:
Keep in mind that `p` above is an `Option` (it's LEFT JOIN after all).

Corrected solution would be something like this:

```
for {
      (e, p) <- echoQuery
               .joinLeft(programsVwQuery).on(_.id === _.id) if e.id.isEmpty
} yield (p.map(_.id))
```

Which in my opinion is a good sign - it actually reads almost like SQL.

**Fully correct solution**

Above generates a kind of join you want without subqueries but if you compare it to your desired query, it actually doesn't produce what you are aiming at. If `Slick` can often be read as SQL than if our SQL is like this (your desired version):

```
SELECT f.`id`
FROM `Full`.`programs_vw` f
LEFT JOIN `FULL`.`Echo` e ON f.`id`=e.`id`
WHERE e.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY f.`id`;
```

than exact mapping to Slick version would look like this:

```
 val query =
 (for {
          (p, e) <- programsVwQuery
                    .joinLeft(echoQuery).on(_.id === _.id) if e.map(_.id).isEmpty
 } yield (p.id))).sortBy(id => id)

db.run(query.result)  // this runs the query
```

Basically you go exactly as in SQL in this case. **It matches your desired query perfectly**. If you take a look at generated SQL is exactly what you wanted at the beginning.

Comment: How to run the query?

Comment: thanks. Your solution works. 
Only one change though .. I had to use if e.map(_.id).isEmpty for filtering.

Comment: thanks. Your solution works. 
Only one change though .. I had to use if e.map(_.id).isEmpty for filtering.

Comment: Definitely, missed that. Incorporated your correction into example. Thanks!